# Fundamentals - Variable Reference

Tags: javascript, variables

Apologies if my terminology is off in this question.

Take the following function:

```
i = 1;
v = i * 2;

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
    console.log(v);
    i++;
    }
```

The console will return 2, 2, 2, 2.  When I encountered this I moved the variable "v" inside the for loop and it returns the expected values of 2, 4, 6, 8.  My understanding of the way that variables work at a fundamental level is obviously wrong.

My logic told me that the value of variable v is permanently related to the value of variable i.  As such, each time v is referred to, the value of i must also be referred to.  Since i will numerically increase, then v should increase in proportion to this.  Instead it appears that the *resultant value* of v is stored, and not the actual expression that calculates this value initially.

This is a first principles question, and whilst I managed to find a solution to the issue I don't understand why this solution worked.

Comment: Absolute miss-click, resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first way

```
i = 1;
// v is equal to the result of "i * 2" (2) and will stay that way 
// until it (v) is set to another value (which never happens)
v = i * 2;

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
    console.log(v);
    i++;
}
```

2nd way

```
i = 1;

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
    // v is equal to i*2, we are setting v each iteration. in each iteration, i is
    // changed. so the value of v will be different 
    v = i * 2; 
    console.log(v);
    i++;
}
```

If for whatever reason you didn't want to explicitly set `v` each time within the loop, you could create a function:

```
i = 1;
v = function(){ return i * 2 };

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
    console.log(v());
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea with a function. Maybe this can be used with getters to create variables that look like variables but are functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, variables will only store the actual value, that was assigned to them and not the logic, that created that value.

So this line of code:

```
v = 2 * i;
```

will calculate `2 * i` and then creates a variable `v`, that points to result of the calculation. So, this should explain why your first example doesn't work the way it was intended to.

In you second example you put that statment inside the for loop:

```
for (...) {
    v = 2 * i;
    i++;
}
```

Now, `v` will be reassigned in every iteration and the expression `2 * i` will be reevaluted everytime. And since `i` is increased in every iteration, `v` will increase also, which results in the desired output.

Comment: Regarding the value being stored, and not the expression used to create them, is there a reason for this?

Comment: it would result in an increasing runtime and memory usage, especially when you consider long chains, like `var a = 1; var b = a + 1; var c = b + 1; ...`. Also you could produce circular dependencies: `var a = 1; var b = a + 1; a = b + 1;` What is a and what is `b` in that example?